# Linq eager load chain entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

Why candidate.Qualification is always null in all followings attempts:

```
var candidate = await _acceptedOfferRepository.GetAll()
                                              .Include(c => c.Candidate)
                                              .Where(ao => ao.Candidate.Id == candidateId && ao.EmployerId.Id == employerId)
                                              .Select(c => c.Candidate)
                                              .Include(c => c.Qualification)
                                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Or:

```
var candidate = await _acceptedOfferRepository.GetAll()
                                              .Include(c => c.Candidate.Qualification)
                                              .Where(ao => ao.Candidate.Id == candidateId && ao.EmployerId.Id == employerId)
                                              .Select(c => c.Candidate)
                                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Or:

```
var candidate = await _acceptedOfferRepository.GetAll()
                                              .Include(c => c.Candidate)
                                              .ThenInclude(c => c.Candidate.Qualification)
                                              .Where(ao => ao.Candidate.Id == candidateId && ao.EmployerId.Id == employerId)
                                              .Select(c => c.Candidate)
                                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

- There is a 1:1 relationship between Candidate and his\her
  Qualification
- The _acceptedOfferRepository.GetAll() returns
  IQueryable

I think something is wrong with the Select() before the FirstOrDefaultAsync(). As soon as I remove that it works fine and all the chained entities are loaded properly. But then it returns the first AcceptedOffer whereas I need the Candidate!

Comment: What does the `GetAll` method do/return? We need to know far more abou tyour code. Also, your indentation is really hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Queries from failed attempts fall into [Ignored includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes) category:

> If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that the query began with, then the include operators are ignored.

They are pretty much like the example from the link. Queries start with `AcceptedOffer`, but then `Select` changes the result type to `Candidate`, hence all `Include` / `ThenInclude` are simply ignored.

First thing I would suggest is to configure EF Core to throw exception for ignored includes as explained in the link:

```
optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings
    .Throw(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning));
```

Second, try building your entity returning queries starting from the entity you want to return. For instance, with your sample it could be something like this (in case you have inverse navigation property from `Candidate` to `AcceptedOffer` and corresponding repository):

```
var candidate = await _candidateRepository.GetAll()
    .Include(c => c.Qualification)
    .Include(c => c.AcceptedOffers) // optional
    .Where(c => c.Id == candidateId && 
        c.AcceptedOffers.Any(ao => ao.EmployerId.Id == employerId))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
var candidate = (await _acceptedOfferRepository.GetAll()
                                          .Include(c => c.Candidate)
                                          .ThenInclude(c => c.Candidate.Qualification)
                                          .Where(ao => ao.Candidate.Id == candidateId && ao.EmployerId.Id == employerId)
                                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync())?.Candidate;
```

But still not quite sure why the Select() was not loading the Qualification!